PayPal sandbox webhook signature verification fails for an event but succeeds for another
I'm using Python with FastAPI:
This are my endpoints. The first receives a checkout order completed event and, if valid, triggers the payment capture. The payment capture webhook sends another notification, payment capture completed, which is caught by the second endpoint. if valid, proceeds with other operations.
@app.post("/capture_payment") # receives a CHECKOUT.ORDER.APPROVED event
async def handle_webhook(request: Request):
    headers = request.headers
    event = await request.json()
    payment_processor = PayPalPayment()
    verification = payment_processor.verify_webhook_signature(headers, event)['verification_status']
    if verification == 'SUCCESS':
        print('Validated!')
        order_id = event['resource']['id']
        result = payment_processor.capture_order(order_id) //event that triggers the webhook below
        return {"code" : 200}
    else:
        return {"code": 400}

@app.post("/register_payment") # receives a PAYMENT.CAPTURE.COMPLETED event
async def handle_webhook(request: Request):
    headers = request.headers
    event = await request.json()
    payment_processor = PayPalPayment()
    verification = payment_processor.verify_webhook_signature(headers, event)['verification_status']
    if verification == 'SUCCESS':
        print('Valid payment capture event received!')   
        #OTHER OPERATIONS
        return {'code' : 200}
    print('Webhook not verified!')
    return {'code' : 400} 

This is my verification function:
    def verify_webhook_signature(self, webhook_headers, event):
        auth_algo = webhook_headers['PAYPAL-AUTH-ALGO']
        cert_url = webhook_headers['PAYPAL-CERT-URL']
        transmission_id = webhook_headers['PAYPAL-TRANSMISSION-ID']
        transmission_sig = webhook_headers['PAYPAL-TRANSMISSION-SIG']
        transmission_time = webhook_headers['PAYPAL-TRANSMISSION-TIME']
        webhook_id = get_webhook_id(event['event_type'])
        
        url = 'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/verify-webhook-signature'
        
        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': f'Bearer {get_bearer_token()}',
        }

        data = {
            'auth_algo': auth_algo,
            'cert_url': cert_url,
            'transmission_id': transmission_id, 
            'transmission_sig': transmission_sig,
            'transmission_time': transmission_time,
            'webhook_id': webhook_id,
            'webhook_event': event
        }

        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
        
        return response.json()

        
def get_webhook_id(event_type : str):
    id = os.getenv(f'PAYPAL_WEBHOOK_ID_{event_type.upper()}')
    print(f'webhook id: {id}')
    return id

The CHECKOUT.ORDER.APPROVED verification is successful, but the PAYMENT.CAPTURE.COMPLETED one is inexplicably failing. It doesn't appear to be a matter of call order, either. I tried them individually in postman and the results remain the same. Any ideas? Does this have anything to do with the fact that I'm in sandbox mode?

instead of request.json(), try event = await request.text() or request.body or similar  and use that raw value for verification rather than re-serializing parsed JSON

I'm trying raw = await request.body() and then composing the request body as `data = {
#other fields,
'webhook_event': raw
}
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)` but I'm met with ''Error: bytes object is not JSON serializable"


Try casing/converting it to a string or something before putting it in data. Just don't parse it to JSON for verification purposes, as converting to JSON and then back to a string can result in different ordering of fields (verification requires the raw string, unaltered)

Ugh I want to kill myself, the webhook ID was incorrect. Anyway, if someone stumbles across this due to a legitimate validation error, the method proposed by Preston looks like this put to code: raw = await.request.body() and the payload is composed as `payload = '{'+f'"auth_algo":"{auth_algo}","cert_url":"{cert_url}","transmission_id":"{transmission_id}","transmission_sig":"{transmission_sig}","transmission_time":"{transmission_time}","webhook_id":"{webhook_id}","webhook_event":'+raw.decode('utf-8')+'}'
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)`    Thanks for helping!
